# Oracle SQL - max() with NULL values

Tags: sql, oracle, null

I have a table that has a series of time based events, each bound with a start and end date. For the most recent (current) event, the end date is NULL. Im trying to collapse the duplicative rows and only show the earliest start date and the latest end date. With the NULL being in the date field, that row is ignored. I can dummy up an end date value with NVL(), but that will cause the front end logic to search for and replace that value.

Is there anyway to get max() function to sort NULL as high?

```
CREATE TABLE CONG_MEMBER_TERM
(
  CONG_MEMBER_TERM_ID  NUMBER(10)               NOT NULL,
  CHAMBER_CD           VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)        NOT NULL,
  CONG_MEMBER_ID       NUMBER(10)               NOT NULL,
  STATE_CD             CHAR(2 BYTE)             NOT NULL,
  DISTRICT             NUMBER(10),
  START_DT             TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE,
  END_DT               TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE
)
```

This query works, but drops the row where end date is NULL.

```
select CONG_MEMBER_ID, 
       district, 
       min(start_dt), 
       max(end_dt)
  from CONG_MEMBER_TERM
 where CONG_MEMBER_ID = 1716
 group by CONG_MEMBER_ID, district;
```

This query fixes that, but now I have a "dummy" end date value(9/9/9999). Something I would rather not have to code around.

```
select CONG_MEMBER_ID, 
       district, 
       min(start_dt), 
       max(nvl(end_dt, to_date('9/9/9999', 'mm/dd/yyyy')))
  from CONG_MEMBER_TERM
 where CONG_MEMBER_ID = 1716
 group by CONG_MEMBER_ID, district;
```

Thanks.

Comment: You have a lot of questions where you have not accepted an answer, you'll get more interest in your questions if you can go back and mark answers correct (using the tick outline to the left of the answer).

Comment: I wasn't even aware of the Accept feature.  Will go back and update some of the older answers.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`max(end_dt) keep (dense_rank first order by end_dt desc nulls first)`

**upd:**

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bc735/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (val int, s date, e date)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO t (val, s, e)
         VALUES (1, sysdate-3, sysdate-2)
    INTO t (val, s, e)
         VALUES (1, sysdate-2, sysdate-1)
    INTO t (val, s, e)
         VALUES (1, sysdate-1, null)
    INTO t (val, s, e)
         VALUES (2, sysdate-1, sysdate-.5)
    INTO t (val, s, e)
         VALUES (2, sysdate-.5, sysdate-.25)
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select val, min(s), max(e) keep (dense_rank first order by e desc nulls first)
from t group by val
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bc735/1/0)**:

```
| VAL |                          MIN(S) | MAX(E)KEEP(DENSE_RANKFIRSTORDERBYEDESCNULLSFIRST) |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1 | November, 13 2012 14:15:46+0000 |                                            (null) |
|   2 | November, 15 2012 14:15:46+0000 |                   November, 16 2012 08:15:46+0000 |
```

Comment: Hmmmm, dense rank.  Not up on these analytic functions. Will give it a whirl and see if I can get it working. Looks promising.

Comment: I need this similar syntax for MS SQL Server... is there any idea?

Comment: I found out that this solution works also on Oracle 10g (10.2.0.3.0).

Answer (score 2):

```
select CONG_MEMBER_ID 
,      district
,      min(start_dt)
,      NULLIF(MAX(NVL(end_dt
                     ,TO_DATE('9999-09-09','YYYY-MM-DD')
                     )
                 )
             ,TO_DATE('9999-09-09','YYYY-MM-DD')
             )
from  CONG_MEMBER_TERM
where CONG_MEMBER_ID = 1716
group by CONG_MEMBER_ID
,        district
;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.