# SQL/Oracle: How to fetch start date row and end date from separate rows for single employee having multiple records in Employee table?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-tuning

The problem with Employee table is that EMployeeID is coming twice (person id is unique).
Creating view which return single data for employee id.
Use case:

```
EMPID     PID     Name    StartDate   End Date .......More Fields

217121  761331  Tefan   21-FEB-19   31-AUG-20
217121  767001  Tefan   01-SEP-20   null
602315  767002  Wolf    01-SEP-20   null
602315  764321  Wolf    01-DEC-15   31-AUG-20
766470  766472  Deva    14-JUL-20   31-DEC-22
```

- Emp ID with single record should come as it is
- Emp ID with two or
  more rows:

  - Consider row: having Startdate <= sysdate (the most recent record only)
  - Consider ENDDATE: from rows having ENDATE> sysdate or ENDDATE=null or latest one

Output should be:

```
217121  761331  Tefan   21-FEB-19   null
602315  764321  Wolf    01-DEC-15   null
766470  766472  Deva    14-JUL-20   31-DEC-22
```

Using SQL/Oracle.

Current query is taking 9 minutes to fetch 30,000 records. (for 50 records taking 5 to 10 seconds which is a lot); i suggest use some different angle:

```
select *  from 
(select t1.*,(select t.enddate from (select enddate,empid,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY enddate desc) as seqnum
  from employee t2
  where t2.empid=t1.empid) t
   where seqnum=1)  As enddate_1 from (select * from
(select WED.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY startdate desc) as seqnum from 
(select t1.*,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY empid) WDECOUNT from employee t1) WED
where WDECOUNT=1 or WED.startdate <= sysdate)) t1 WHERE seqnum=1);
```

Comment: I can't follow the question.  What does "consider" mean?  You are combining values from different rows, but you don't explain the logic.  There appears to be some sort of prioritization.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Consider means the row which should be displayed as end result.

Comment: . . Your result combines values from multiple rows.  You are not showing just a single row.

Comment: But i have given output in respect to my use cases. Can you please elaborate. The row which we need to display is under "consider row" part and in that "consider row" there is column end date and it value comes according to second business rule

Answer (score 1):

If this assertion is true;

> For each EmployeeId, a later StartDate returns a higher PersonId

Then I can suggest using some MAX/MIN to achieve greater efficiency with your query.

Something like this;

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.EMPID, MAX(e.PID), e.Name, MIN(e.startdate), 
MAX(e.enddate) keep (dense_rank first order by enddate desc nulls first)
FROM employee e
WHERE e.startdate <= SYSDATE
GROUP BY e.EMPID, e.Name;
```

Edit; include WHERE startdate < sysdate

Comment: But it is not always that we require that higher person id. 
it may be future employee but today we need to show its previous record and after start date we need to show his new person id record.

Comment: So can't those records be ignored with WHERE startdate <= SYSDATE ?

Comment: No Those can't be ignored. The ROW must be using your above query. Also there are many other fields 90, i have just given certain fields. So Max on PID will it achieve? lemme test

Comment: Also min start date will not work as it will return min date always. Suppose we have 3 records and we require record 2 then it returns minimum date

Comment: Above query is not returning null

Comment: I was working with the sample data and output you provided, which min startdate is correct for. If there are additional columns involved, then my suggested approach is probably not going to be entirely appropriate. I tested the dense_rank nulls first from this post and it worked for me; https://stackoverflow.com/a/13418250/8194026

Comment: Can you see my query and suggest how can i improve time of same?

Comment: I have increase performance using following; but still looking for more:

(
select t1.*,
(SELECT * from (SELECT wec.ENDDATE from actualtable_core wec WHERE wec.EMPLOYEEID = t1.EMPLOYEEID order by wec.ENDDATE DESC) 
where rownum=1)
as  enddate_1 

from 
(select * from
(select WED.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY employeeid ORDER BY startdateconcern desc) as seqnum from 
(select t1.*,COUNT(*)
OVER (PARTITION BY employeeid) WDECOUNT from employee_internal t1) WED
where WDECOUNT=1 or WED.startdateconcern <= sysdate)) t1 WHERE seqnum=1);